# How to test HTTP request in PhpStorm

Tags: http, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to test a HTTP Request in PhpStorm :

```
POST /api/public/v1/manage/init_partners HTTP/1.1
Host: api.payota.net
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 412

{...}
```

When I try to run the file inside the IDE, I got this error :

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to api.payota.net:80 [api.payota.net/18.185.181.64, api.payota.net/3.120.46.2] failed: Connection timed out: connect

I'm trying to do it from local.
How can I configure PhpStorm to run correctly my HTTP requests ? I did not find yet.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#composing-http-requests I would just use `POST https://api.payota.net/api/public/v1/manage/init_partners` instead of first 2 lines. **P.S.** Try sending test  requests to https://httpbin.org/ -- do they work?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @LazyOne, it seems to work like this :

```
POST https://api.payota.net/api/public/v1/manage/init_partners
Content-Type: application/json 
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 412

{...}
```